# Prevent Pandas df.style.to_latex() from escaping characters

Tags: python, pandas, latex

Using pandas df.to_latex() in pandas 1.4.2 gives a future warning that recommends using df.style.to_latex() instead. In the df.to_latex() method it was possible to prevent pandas from escaping characters using escape=False. df.style.to_latex() does not except escape as a keyword. Is there any way to prevent character escaping in df.style.to_latex()?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you *don't* want to escape anything, you should not need the escape parameter anymore!

---

If you want to change something about how characters are escaped:

You have to format your styler, which has the option to select how to escape characters, see the first example in the api reference:

[api reference to_latex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex.html)

which mentions the use of

[style.format](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html) and [style.format_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html)

to format your text.